# sql query to get the column value again in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005-express

```
select *, 
case when number = '12' and status = 'y' then cost
end as [price]
from tblx
```

i got the results from the above query, i want to use the value of price column, again in case statement of the same query as like below

```
select *, 
case when number = '12' and status = 'y' then cost-500
end as [price],
case when price = 24 then trasdate end as [trasdate]
from tblx
```

If my question is not clear, please suggest me

I am working in a stored procedure with more than two joins connecting 8 tables, i just want to get the column value again to use it on case statement on the same query, I shortened the question as the query is bigger.

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: if you can't, then why don't you put the whole first clause in the second case?

Comment: I want to get the price column value to validate in case when then of the same query.

Comment: You can't reference an alias that was created at the same scope. Consider using a CTE or subquery, e.g. `SELECT *, CASE WHEN price = 24 THEN trasdate END as trasdate FROM (SELECT *, case when number = '12' ... AS price FROM tblx) AS x;`

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, Thank You. The query worked in the table, but i am unable to execute from the stored procedure

Comment: @jarlh,@Gordon Linoff,@ergonaut. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same query you need to just duplicate the same case statement where you've attempted to reference it. Btw you should probably add an else 0 to it because currently it'll return null if your conditions don't evaluate to true which could affect its usage in the other case statement.

There are other options if you don't want to duplicate the case statement e.g.:

- use the price statement in a sub query and reference it by name in an outer query
- use a temp table with price added as a calculated column
- as above but use a table variable

Just repeating the statement is obviously simplest and may well perform best too, downside is duplication. In terms of performance, test for your likely use case.

Comment: Your answer enables me to have a idea to execute, apart from case expression, Thanks for your efforts

Comment: No problem, feel free to tick my answer if you're happy with it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, 
   case when number = '12' and status = 'y' then cost end price,
   case when number = '12' and status = 'y' 
         and cost = 24 then trasdate end [trasdate]
from tblx
```

Comment: This works, but is redundant, and gets worse when the expression to repeat gets more complex.